# No detecta la Collision de mi Game Object

Tags: c#, unity, unity3d

[image: No detecta la collision de mi player]

Basicamente son trampas que salen al hazar , estoy haciendo un endless runner , pero cuando la trampa choca con mi player la escena no se reinicia , ¿Alguna solución?

Comment: Pon el código _como texto, con formato_. No todos pueden ver las imágenes. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score 0):

El código parece estar bien, pero hay que tener en cuenta ciertas cosas como:

- Revisar si los obstáculos o el player tienen su componente de Collider con la opción de trigger activada (en este caso, en lugar de OnCollisionEnter, se usa OnTriggerEnter).
- A juzgar por el OnCollisionEnter, el juego es en 3D, pero si es 2D, la función es OnCollisionEnter2D, o en tal caso, OnTriggerEnter2D.
- Podrías usar una confirmación para detectar específicamente los obstáculos usando tags (CompareTag("Nombre del tag")).

Funciona también para el OnCollisionEnter y OnTriggerEnter y OnTriggerEnter2D.

Comment: Hola Federico Krug, te sugiero que elimines tu respuesta para evitar recibir votos negativos, estás respondiendo una pregunta mal formulada, que fue hecha hace meses, y para más... inri, tu respuesta no parece tener relación con el código del OP.